# Why PinObject has a value in my view but is null in my OnAfterRenderAsync() in Blazor component?

Tags: leaflet, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to get an object from another component and use it so I can add a pin on my leaflet map. When I have @PinObject.Name it gives me the data and all the fields are populated. However in my OnAfterRenderAsync() method the PinObject is null. How can I fix this?
The get_coordinates_from_address_async takes a list of objects or a single object and it works accordingly. For PinObjects it works as expected, but not for PinObject and I don't get why.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        this.firstRender = false;

        module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./map-integration.js");
        if (module != null)
        {
            result = await module.InvokeAsync<string>("get_coordinates_from_address_async", PinObjects, PinObject);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change to oninitializedasync, tried breakpoints, everything works but somehow the pinObject is always null ein OnAfterRenderAsync. tried to put an if to check if pinObject is null and it didn't work. How Can I make it wait for the PinObject?

Update: It works if I add an  await Task.Delay(1000);

I call it Like:

<MyProgram.Components.PinLObjectMap PinObject="@ViewModel.PinObject" ShowMap="true" />

and PinObject from my Pins Map is initialized in my ViewModel like:

PinObject = await _pinRequest.GetPinById(PinId);

Comment: The answer is that you are rendering the page before you have populated the object, but to know why we need to see the code where you get `PinObject.`  As an aside, you almost certainly shouldn't be calling `StateHasChanged();` where you do.  It's not needed

Comment: "It works if I add an await Task.Delay(1000);".  That's a kludge not a solution.